# How to retrieve data from multiple selected rows in a table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am using MS Access 2007. I have a form that has inserted a subform. The subform appears essentially as a grid of rows and columns of data, with each row representing a record in a table.

I have a button on the main form, which when clicked, fetches data from the currently selected row in the subform.  The table in the subform is essentially a list of latitude and longitude values, in degrees, minutes, seconds. Here is the code that gets run when the main form button is clicked:

```
Dim LatLong As String
Screen.PreviousControl.SetFocus
LatLong = Me.Results.Form.LatitudeDegrees.Value & "+" & _
        Me.Results.Form.LatitudeMinutes.Value & "+" & _
        Me.Results.Form.LatitudeSeconds.Value & "+N,+" & _
        Me.Results.Form.LongitudeDegrees.Value & "+" & _
        Me.Results.Form.LongitudeMinutes.Value & "+" & _
        Me.Results.Form.LongitudeSeconds.Value & "+W"

Launch ("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" & LatLong & "&hl=en&t=h")
```

This will display a push-pin on a google map at the LatLong coordinate. This works fine.

What I want to do now is display push-pins for MULTIPLE selected rows that exist in the subform's table. I don't know how to do this.  I can handle passing data to google maps, that's not a problem. What I don't know how to do is retrieve values from MULTIPLE selected rows in the subform's table.  The above code only retrieves the FIRST record's values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a datagrid on that subform?  If so, consider using a multi-select listbox instead.  Then you could use something like this (you will need to change all the variables, obviously...):

```
Private Sub testmultiselect_Click()
    Dim oItem As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

    iCount = 0

    If Me!NamesList.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each oItem In Me!NamesList.ItemsSelected
            If iCount = 0 Then
                sTemp = sTemp & Me!NamesList.ItemData(oItem)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            Else
                sTemp = sTemp & "," & Me!NamesList.ItemData(oItem)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Next oItem
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing was selected from the list", vbInformation
        Exit Sub  'Nothing was selected
    End If

    Me!mySelections.Value = sTemp
End Sub
```

Comment: >> Are you using a datagrid on that subform? <<

No. The subform is another form, on which are text boxes linked to a table. The result is that when this form is inserted as a subform, it will appear as a grid with rows and columns.

Comment: I'm unclear as to how you can select multiple "rows" if all you have is text boxes.  You MUST have your form set up to display as a datagrid, or you can't possibly select multiple records.

Comment: If a subform's "Default format" property is set to "Datasheet", it will appear within the main form as a grid with rows and columns.

Comment: OK, you said it was text boxes.  Anyway, you can't do it with a datasheet, you have to use a listbox.  There's no way to iterate through records in a datasheet.

Comment: The subform was created as a regular form, of course.  On that regular form, if you were to open it directly (and not as a subform insertion), the form would be seen to contain text boxes on it, linked to fields in a table.

Comment: Are you opening it as a regular form?  If not, that's useless information.  If you want to argue semantics, I could say "The subform appears essentially as a grid of rows and columns of data" should have been written as "The subform is set to Datasheet mode".  The end result is still; you can't iterate through a datasheet.  If you want to do what you're talking about, your best bet is to dump the data into a multiselect Listbox and use the code I posted above.